# Python lists within dictionaries

Tags: python

Now i know there is some coverage of this topic already but i can't understand it. I'll show you my code and i hope this helps you understand where i'm at.

Dictionary

```
father = {"Yin": ["yang","yaha"]}
```

This code works fine.

```
elif choice == "5":
    son = input("Enter the name of a son to get the name of his grandfather: ")
    if son in father:
        description = father[son]
        print("\n", son, "'s grandfather is", description[1])
    else:
        print("\nSorry, I don't know who that is", son)
```

This code doesn't, I just want it to be able to change the second item in the list(yaha).

```
elif choice == "6":
    son = input("which grandfather and son pair need updating: ")
    if son in father:
        description = input("What's name of the grandfather?: ")
        son[father] = description[1]
        print("\n", son, "has been redefined.")
    else:
        print("\nThat person doesn't exist!  Try adding it.")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean

```
father[son][1] = description
```

in the second snippet.

Explanation:

- `father` is a dict, `son` is a string, so `son[father]` will raise an `AttributeError`.
- `description` is also a string, so `description[1]` is a single character. `father[son]`, on the other hand, is a list, and you can assign its element to a new string.

Comment: OMG! Thank you, i tried putting [1] almost everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
description = input("What's name of the grandfather?: ")
son[father] = description
```

because description is a string